# gridview not showing along with AJAX TabPanel when using Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tabcontainer

Ok, so i am using Site.Master to use same layout for all my pages, i have done everything that i think should work, but My AJAXTabPanel is not showing in it's div (it's not showing at all but you can see the div there). Here is my Site.Master code:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SMC.SiteMaster" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Sigma Medicare</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link href="Styles/HP.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Styles/Styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <header id="header">
                    <div id="contentholder">
                        <span id="logo">
                            <img src="Images/logo.png" /></span>
                        <div id="linkholder">
                            <ul id="links">
                                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <div id="linkholder">
                            <ul id="links">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="LoginPage.aspx" style="color: grayText">Login</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="RegisterationForm.aspx" style="color: GrayText">Registeration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Menu creation-->
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="HomePage.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="Patient.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Patient Care</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="DoctorPage.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Doctors</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="" style="color: #FFFFFF">Appointments</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="Departments.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Departments</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="BloodBank.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Blood Bank</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="" text="About Us" style="color: #FFFFFF"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <!-- Main image -->
                <div id="image">
                    <img src="Images/hosp2.jpg" alt="Sigma Medicare" />
                </div>
               <div id="mbody"> 
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                   </div>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p id="copyrt">Copyright &copy <%: DateTime.Now.Year %>, by Sigma Medicare. All rights reserved.</p>
                <br />
            </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my ASPX code: (only the part needed is included)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin_Panel_Schedule.aspx.cs" Inherits="SMC.Admin_Panel_Schedule" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    <div class="gview">
                        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="700px" ScrollBars="Both" Height="330px">
                            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Cardiology" ID="TabPanel1">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                        <Columns>
                  //Data bound columns                          
                                        </Columns>


 </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
  </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
   </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

I'll be honest, i haven't worked with Site.Master before so i am a little stumped. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: As an aside, your grid has `AutoGenerateColumns=false` but you comment `//auto generated columns `.

Comment: i meant data bound columns, sorry.

Comment: To any takers.. Will it be ok if i don't use site master? I mean it is absolutely necessary to use it? My forms were working fine before i decided to use Site.Master.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the closing tags of the `</div>` and the `</TabContainer>`.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="gview">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="700px" ScrollBars="Both" Height="330px">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Cardiology" ID="TabPanel1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                        <Columns>
  //auto generated columns                          
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </TabContainer>
     </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

**Edit**: Since you've edited your question now that seemed to be a typo.

---

But the screenshot that you have posted in a comment to my answer shows that visual studio doesn't like the `TagPrefix` asp that you are using for the asp.net-ajax controls:

[image]

(original link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb6v9.png)

For the `TabContainer` you are using `ajaxToolKit` which is not underlines, therefore seems to be the correct one. You can specify it here:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit" %>
```

So either change that `TagPrefix` to `asp` or change (f.e.) `<asp:TabPanel ...` to `<ajaxToolKit:TabPanel ...`.

Comment: no sorry, it is there, i just forgot to type it here.

Comment: To any takers.. Will it be ok if i don't use site master? I mean it is absolutely necessary to use it? My forms were working fine before i decided to use Site.Master.

Comment: If everything was working fine, then this indicates that you missed out something from your master page. Either an opening/closing tag or a reference. What happens if you move this to the master page:
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

Comment: @SanaQureshi:  if you have forgotten to type the closing tags here, is it possible that you also have forgotten to add other relevant code? Why don't you copy-paste it instead?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5w1fqe this is what happens. for TabPanel it says "it's not a known element", and for the rest it says, "not supported"

Comment: @SanaQureshi: you are using `asp` for the asp.net-ajax controls like `TabPanel`, but you need to use `ajaxToolKit` because that works for `TabContainer`, so it seems that you have specified that `TagPrefix`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: nope, still didn't work.. http://prntscr.com/5w1p0b
Will it be ok if i don't use site master? I mean it is absolutely necessary to use it?

Comment: @SanaQureshi: in general you don't need to use a `MasterPage`, but if you want to use the same layout or menu everywhere it is recommended.